# Certificate in JNLP application

Tags: java, jnlp

I have created an installer from JNLP application. I mean earlier,I had a JNLP based application which is deployed in the server,now I created an `.msi` package from this deployed application.My problem is when I install my application from the installer then in beginning I am getting Warning-Security dialog box which says that application certificate can not be verified,do you want to run the application.

My question,Is there any way to include this certificate some where in the installer so that this message box can be avoided.

Comment: See my edit below, I added how to add sign to MSI file

Comment: Why would you want to use WebStart to launch a locally installed application? Just launch yout main-jar using a local java-VM, setting the right classpath and other options and you won't have any trouble with code-signing.

Answer (score 0):

**As I know you need to buy it.**

For developing you can create your local Certificate that will work only on your computer.

Here some information how to do that:

**install SDK tool**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11310

http://margopowell.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/installing-microsoft-signtool-exe/

https://bytescout.com/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=296

generate PFX file derived from private key and sertificate

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Bin>makecert.exe -sv MyProgram.pvk -n "CN=MY DIGITAL KEY" MyProgram.cer
```

Succeeded

public key and private key password: mypasssword

**run:**

```
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk MyProgram.pvk -spc MyProgram.cer -pfx MyProgram.pfx
```

**MyProgram.pfx file should appear**

for Inno Setup for example

```
$(ISCC) "/sMyProgram=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Bin\signtool.exe sign /f C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Bin\MyProgram.pfx /p mypasssword $p" $(ISS_SCRIPT)
```

**How to digitally sign MSI**

```
signtool.exe sign /f MyPfxFile.pfx /p MyPrivateKeyPassword /d "My Product Name" /du "http://www.myproducturl.com" /t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll" "MyInstaller.msi"
```

see [link](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/stuartpreston/archive/2007/02/19/Automating-signtool.exe-_2800_or-how-to-make-a-PFX-file-from-a-PVK-and-SPC-file_21002900_.aspx)

Hope it will help you

Comment: I have to deploy this application in various machine and I have this certificate also. But it is not included in the installer that's why application is not recognizing. Since, I don't have any experience on Certificate related stuff ,so,Its hard for me to understand its process.

Comment: You need create pfx file and use it as argument for ccreation application installer. I showed you how to do that with Inno Setup. And I answered on your question :)